# Search only shows results when logged in

Tags: search

My search results are currently only showing results if I am logged into the back end, I only using SearchWP's Modal Form and no additional search plugins, what could be causing this?

Comment: Does it work fine if you disable SearchWP? If you're using a plugin for search you should contact its author for assistance.

Comment: I am using the default search function, just SearchWP for the Modal Box